# Can a passanger door window just shatter if it's off track?

Tags: power-windows, buick

Okay, I have 2000 Buick Regal LS that I bought from my aunt. One of the back passenger door windows was stuck to where it remains up. Just recently, it has been deciding to finally fall down while driving. So, of course, I push the window up everyday after every trip I make. Well, yesterday I go out to my car and I notice the window is completely shattered into numerous pieces. My question to you, can a window shatter if its off track? How much, an estimate, would it cost to fix the window?

Answer (score 2):

Side windows are tempered glass. They are made to shatter into a million pieces (as you just found out). All it takes is pressure in the right place in the right direction to have it shatter. Can it being off track cause this? I would assume there was just enough stress in the right place and that's all she wrote. I had shut a car door once with the window partially down and it shattered. Realistically it doesn't take much to make the window shatter, so it could happen with it just being off track.